# URL PARAMETER - JAVA

Tags: java, url, parameters

I am doing an desktop application using Java that can send SMS to a multiple phone numbers via browser. To send the SMS, I need to put in parameters that username, password, message to be sent and the recipient's number.

I have used this and it worked but the problem is it opens up a browser to every recipient so it is not advisable especially if its going to be sent to a lot:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String url = String.format("http://www.companysms.com/RemoteAPI/SendSMS.aspx?username=%s&encoding=url&password=%s&messagedata=%s&receiver=%s&binary=0", txtUsername.getText(),txtPassword.getText(), txtMessage.getText(),tblMessage.getValueAt(i, 2));
rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+ url);
```

I have tried this one too but it gives me the HTTP response code 400:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.connect();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        results.append(line);
    }

    connection.disconnect();
```

If I use the URLencoder with "UTF-8", it makes it worse because i cant be sure of what the message the user will send and if they will use any of the special characters. Is there a way to have the first set of codes that I used to not open browser after sending the SMS or is there another way of doing this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your second approach using `HttpURLConnection` looks right, and you should try to find out why the server of your SMS sending provider returns a 400.

Comment: You should not `setDoOutput(true)` on a GET request (GET is prohibited from having a body) and need not `setRequestMethod("GET")` since it is the default. Make sure everything in your URL is encoded where necessary; a browser may do that for you automatically (at least the browsers I use do so for data from the address bar) but Java's `URL` class does not and most 'special characters' are not valid in a URL.

Comment: Okay. I removed the setRequestMethod and setDoOutput but it still keeps giving me the error of HTTP response code 400. I pasted in browser the URL it produced when I ran it thru Debug mode and it sent the message. So the URL if pasted in a browser, the message gets sent but from the codes, it gives the error.

Comment: Was able to figure out the error why it's giving that error. It's the spaces in the actual message to be sent. I replace all spaces to "%20"  and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.